# How to run the same copy of Eclipse on Windows host & Linux VM?

Tags: virtualbox, eclipse

I develop on both Windows (host) and Linux (VM) for good reasons.

I get frustrated trying to keep Eclipse in sych when I develop cross platform programs.

It occurs to me that as Eclipse is a Java program, I ought to be able to install it on a shared drive and run it from both host & VM (sharing the code too).

Of course, I would have to tweak the projects for tool-chain, but my question is:

> has anyone run the same version of Eclipse (mainly CDT) from both a Widows host & a Linux VM from a shared folder?

If so, how? Which version to download - the Widows version is a .exe and I can't find a meaningfully names file (like eclipseXXX.jar) on Linux?

Comment: Eclipse is not just a Java program, it includes C code which is specific to the operating system - so you can't do this.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is not just a Java program, it includes some C code which is specific to the operating system - so you can't do this.

The executable that starts up Eclipse is 'eclipse.exe' on Windows but just 'eclipse' on Linux and macOS. The executables only work on the operating system they were built for.

The SWT GUI code used by Eclipse is also OS dependent.

Comment: I had hoped that those executables would simply `java -jar eclipse.jar` :-(

Comment: You can start Eclipse using the `java` command (see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)) but that doesn't solve the SWT code being OS dependent.

Comment: Looks like I have to give up on the idea then. Thanks, all the same :-)